# Difficulty Fetching User Interests from Facebook API in Bubble.io Platform

Tags: facebook, bubble.io

Struggling to Retrieve User Interests via Facebook API in Bubble.io
Problem Overview:
I'm currently developing an application on the Bubble.io platform that involves fetching user interests from Facebook via its API. While I've identified the necessary endpoint to access this data, I'm encountering a roadblock in generating new access tokens for each user who connects their Facebook account to our platform. The Facebook API demands a unique access token for every user connection, and I'm uncertain about how to accomplish this within the Bubble.io environment.

Details and Attempts Made:
API Endpoint Identification: I have successfully located the specific endpoint within the Facebook API that provides access to user interests.

Access Token Requirement: The challenge arises due to the Facebook API's insistence on a new access token for each individual user who integrates their Facebook account with our platform.

Bubble.io Framework: I am developing the application within the Bubble.io framework, which presents limitations and uncertainties regarding the generation of new access tokens for individual users connecting via Facebook.

Seeking Guidance:
I'm reaching out to the community for insights, suggestions, or potential workarounds within the Bubble.io platform to dynamically generate new access tokens for each user linking their Facebook account.

Queries:
Has anyone encountered a similar obstacle in generating individual access tokens for Facebook API integration within Bubble.io?

Are there specific plugins, workflows, or methodologies within Bubble.io that enable the creation of unique access tokens for each user?

Alternatively, are there other recommended approaches or external services that could assist in resolving this issue while working within the Bubble.io framework?

Any guidance, tips, or shared experiences would be immensely helpful in overcoming this challenge. Thank you in advance for any assistance or suggestions provided to help navigate this issue and successfully retrieve user interests from the Facebook API within the Bubble.io platform.

Note: Screenshots, detailed workflows, or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://manual.bubble.io/core-resources/bubble-made-plugins/facebook#scope does not make it sound as if they let you chose what specific permissions to ask for.